# How to make many res folders in one android project for multiple clients?

Tags: android, templates, android-resources

I am developing some app and i will sell a copy from it for many clients but with different ui for every client.

Now i want to make one master app then if there is some issue i want to fix it i can fix in only one project then build different apks for all clients.

First i want to include many res folders which every res folder has the ui, layouts and strings for one client like the following :

[image]

Now *anwar* client has reported some issue then i want to fix it in this main project and build new apk with fixed issue for *anwar* client but i should exclude another clients **res** folders and iclude only this client res folder in apk building to keep the size of apk such as it has only one res folders.

How can i achieve that? Where can i change the client name in some file and it will include only its res folder when building the apk?

Now i have some issue also when i tried to make these res folders .. when i open any xml file i found this error :

[image]

it says `URI is not registered (Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Schemas and DTDs)`

So how can i achieve that ??
Thanks in adavnce!

Comment: You need to define sourceSet in your app gradle and inside android tag.

sourceSets {
      
        main {
            res {
                srcDirs 'src/main/res', 'src/main/res_anwar', 'src/main/res_forsan'
            }
        }
    }

Comment: i searched now and i think it will be better to use flavors

Comment: Flavours you need to if you need to compile different sets of resources still you need to define different sourceSet in your flavour.